# "Missing" Apartment Rent Payment

Tags: rental-property, australia, rent, real-estate-leasing

So I'm currently renting an apartment through real estate agent. I've been paying monthly. They claimed that they didn't receive the May payment and there is no unclaimed money in their account. I have sent them both the receipt of the transfer and a proof of transaction from the central branch.

But they still threatened me to vacate me out of my apartment as they still say they didn't receive any money. I think that they must have noted or assigned my transfer a wrong apartment owner.

Please advise.

Comment: Which country, state, or city is this happening in? Laws governing rental real estate vary by jurisdiction.

Comment: Is the transfer made to real estate agent or the owner of Apartment? It is possible that Real estate agent may not have forwarded the funds on your behalf to the owner of Apartment.

Comment: @Sarwate its in Australia

Comment: @Dheer I transfered it to a real estate agent then they will transfer it to the owner. I think they may have transfered it to a wrong owner. The real estate agent also said there is no unclaimed funds in their account. Meaning they have transfered/distributed incoming funds to property owners. –

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that either

- the Real Estate Agent has transferred funds to Correct Owner but informed the Owner that this is due to some other tenant
- Or Transferred to incorrect Owner

Your best bet is to work with the Real Estate Agent and advise them of error. You can also advise the Owner and show him receipts of transfer of funds and inform that you are working with the Real Estate Agent to get this resolved ASAP.

Comment: This.  I had a similar experience, but the RE was correct: we had missed a payment.  However, they kept insisting that we'd missed the August payment. I went through all the payments to them for that year and I noticed that we'd actually missed March's payment.  I gave them categorical information (including a receipt **from them**) that we'd made the August payment.  Due to their complete insistence on it being August and no wriggle room, I didn't tell them it was March until they provided us with a full account in writing of what they thought we'd missed.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need some advice and support from a knowledgeable third party who can help you enforce your rights as the tenant of a rental property. I suspect the real estate agent is being heavy-handed with you because they are not able to locate the funds you say you can prove were paid.

You did not answer the question about which state you are in. If you are in Melbourne Victoria, I would contact the tenants help line: (03) 9416 2577.
It's a free and confidential information and basic advice service run by the [Tenants Union of Victoria](https://www.tuv.org.au/tenants-help-line/).

If you are in another Australian State you should be able to find similar organisations to help you by searching on the internet.  Good luck!